# wordpress - site not update after update style.css

Tags: css

After updating the style.css in `Appearance > Theme Editor > stylesheet(style.css)`, I refreshed my site, then saw that the style was not applied.

I've also tried clearing the browser cache and using `cmd + shift + r` to re-download the resources, but it still is not working.

I have NO Cdn enabled.

Is there any way to make the site live for development, or is there any preferred way for development?

In `style.css`

```
...
/*
Author: xxx Limited
Description: This is the template for xxx
Version: 1.0.0. // tried to update the version here but not working
... 
*/
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

This most likely is a caching issue on the server side. Check in your `functions.php` if the stylesheet is [enqueued](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) using the version number. Failing to do so is the most common reason WordPress caching plugins ignore updates to `style.css`. It should look a bit like this:

```
    $theme_data = wp_get_theme();
    wp_enqueue_style('main-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', '', $theme_data['version'], 'all');
```

Otherwise, it might be that the webserver software is caching agressively. In that case waiting a few hours may be your only recourse.